# House MD s5 e18 Here Kitty. Was the cat real or CGI?

Tags: house

I just saw the episode tonight, and the cat didn't seem real to me. The way it was "handled" and it's movement. However, I wonder if the cat audio-track made me perceive it as CGI?

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Kitty)

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason for the cat not to be real. Why would they waste time and money doing a CGI cat, when all they asked of the cat was for it to sit around, and run around? Only to end up with a inferior product?

Common logic dictates the cat was real.

Comment: As further evidence, the extended [cast & crew](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1273721/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) credits on IMDB for this episode lists *"Boone Narr ... animal supplier (uncredited)"*  This suggests that at least one animal was in fact supplied.

Comment: Steve-O, guess it was real, cheers. I looked under cast on IMDB but found nothing, I checked again and it was under "company cast" (a separate section) I would accept this as an answer.
CyberClaw, It is very difficult to get a cat to do what humans want them to do. Salem in Sabrina the teenage witch, was animatronic for a large proportion of shooting. House was holding it strange, shoving it into a bag. If I tried that with my cat, my cat would carve me up. The cat was imperative to the ep, they need it, I don't think the use of cgi/animatronics is an unreasonable thought.

Comment: Salem was a talking cat doing many non cat things. There are many real cats that have no problem being docile and are used to being put in carriers. Cats can be trained...

Comment: They might have used a body double (a stuffed animal) and camera work for any rougher sections of the episode (I don't recall it being shoved into a bag), but there'd be no reason to use one in 99% of the scenes, which were the cat either sitting around, or walking somewhere. I can do that with my (non-trained) cats. To sit them somewhere just drop them there, and 80% of the times they'll stay. If I want to call him somewhere, I just bang silverware into plates or something, he'll just run thinking it's food.

Comment: To extend this answer, and OP's question "However, I wonder if the cat audio-track made me perceive it as CGI?": The cat's audio would have been added on at a later stage (it is considered a sound effect, not dialogue), which means that the sound itself is artificial (not live recorded during the scene recording), and could cause you to notice the "fakeness" of the audio, and therefore the cat who is supposed to be making the sound.